# Map and legend stay empty after export

Tags: pyqgis, layers

I am using the code below to render and export a map layout.

```
layerOSM = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("OpenStreetMap")[0]
layerRegion = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layerName)[0]
print("Nb before filter: ",layerRegion.featureCount())

#Creating filter
condition = ""
if(echelle=='REG'):
    pass
elif(echelle=='DEP'):
    condition = "insee_dep = \'"+str(code_insee)+"\'"
    #condition = "INSEE_DEP = \'"+str(code_insee)+"\'"
elif(echelle=='EPCI'):
    condition = "type = \'COM\' AND code_epci = \'"+str(code_insee)+"\'"
elif(echelle=='COM'):
    condition = "type = \'COM\' AND code_epci = \'"+str(code_insee)+"\'"
layerRegion.setSubsetString(condition)
print("Nb after filter: ",layerRegion.featureCount())

#Selecting layers to use (OpenStreetMap is always visible so not included)
layerList = [layerRegion]

#Make the selected layers visible

for layer in layerList:
    node = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer.id())
    if node:
        node.setItemVisibilityChecked(True)

# Get project and layout manager
project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()


# Delete all existing layouts with the same name
layoutName = 'Layout2'
layouts_list = manager.printLayouts()
for layout in layouts_list:
    if layout.name() == layoutName:
        manager.removeLayout(layout)

# Setting layout
layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.initializeDefaults()
layout.setName(layoutName)
manager.addLayout(layout)

# Creating the map
map = QgsLayoutItemMap(layout)
map.setRect(20, 20, 20, 20)

# Setting map size
ms = QgsMapSettings()

# Selecting layouts to include
print(layerList)
ms.setLayers(layerList)
rect = QgsRectangle(ms.fullExtent())
rect.scale(1.0)
ms.setExtent(rect)
map.setExtent(rect)

# Including map to layout
layout.addLayoutItem(map)


#Adding legend
legend = QgsLayoutItemLegend(layout)
legend.setTitle("Légende")
layerTree = QgsLayerTree()
print("Last number: ",layerList[0].featureCount())
layerTree.addLayer(layerList[0])
legend.model().setRootGroup(layerTree)
layout.addLayoutItem(legend)
legend.setLinkedMap(map)
legend.setLegendFilterByMapEnabled(True)
legend.refresh()
legend.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(210, 15, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))

#Exporting layout
layout = manager.layoutByName(layoutName)
exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
exporter.exportToImage(prjpath+"/export/images/carte_operateurs_"+str(code_insee)+".png", QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings())


#Setting the layer used to 'not visible'
for layer in layerList:
    node = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer.id())
    if node:
        node.setItemVisibilityChecked(False)

#Deleting the condition
layerRegion.setSubsetString("")
```

I tried several times to print the feature number of the layer to check that the filter is correctly working. That seems to be the case but the export file still only shows the "OpenStreetMap" layer (and yes my layer is above the OpenStreetMap one). Oddly, even without applying the filter, I keep having an empty map and legend...
Of course, if I comment on the "legend.setLegendFilterByMapEnabled(True)" line, the entire legend is visible in the export.

The problem could be generated by the layer I used (a basic shapefile) because my code worked with another layer (another shapefile) but I don't what makes this layer so problematic...

Comment: Comment all code after line `#Exporting layout`, run it, open the layout in the GUI with it name and see if it's OK.

Comment: @ThomasG77 I tried this but even in the GUI, the layout is still empty.

Comment: So the issue is not in the export but in the code before